# The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: gradle, react-native

So I am trying to make a release APK of a react-native project but it gives me this gradlew error.
If i run react-native run-android it runs fine.Please Help me with this error[image]

Comment: You should check the environment variable

Comment: It says in the suggestion below to use `.\gradlew` if you trust the command. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as dansiemens said: `.\gradlew assembleRelease` worked for me.